# How can JavaScript call a chain of methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently got a question while looking at the javascript.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

my question is this.

```
function().function();
```

How does this call a function consecutively?
If I want to know more about this grammar, what keyword should I search for?
Thank you.

Comment: You probably want to learn about method chaining, or currying, depending on your use case. If you're not using classes, you want your function to return a function itself, in which case you want to learn more about "first class functions".

Comment: In your example, `createServer()` returns an object that has a `listen()` function, so you can type `createServer().listen()` directly. You could also type `let server = createServer()` followed by `server.listen()`

Comment: My curiosity has been resolved. Thank you both for your prompt reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern you're looking for is [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). It can be implemented pretty easily with JavaScript like this:

```js
const obj = {
    function1() {
        console.log('function1');
        return this;
    },
    
    function2() {
        console.log('function2');
        return this;
    }
}

obj.function1().function2().function1();
```

You could also use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in case of asynchronous functions like this:

```js
const delay = fun => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => [resolve, fun].forEach(x => x()), 1000));

const obj = {
    promise: Promise.resolve(),

    function1() {
        this.promise = this.promise.then(() => delay(() => console.log('function1')));
        return this;
    },
    
    function2() {
        this.promise = this.promise.then(() => delay(() => console.log('function2')));
        return this;
    }

}

obj.function1().function2().function1();
```

Comment: Thank you for example. You are a guru.

Comment: You're welcome, check the asynchronous version if you're interested!

Comment: I don't know Promise yet, but I was going to study it. Thank you very much for the new example.

Answer (score 0):

`http.createServer` function returns an object with property `listen` which is a function, the function is called immediatelly after object is created.

```
function getDog(dogName) {
    return {
        name: dogName,
        bark: function () {
            console.log("woof woof"); 
        }
    }
}

let dog1 = getDog("wolfie").bark();
// is the same as
let dog1 = getDog("wolfie");
dog1.bark();
```

Comment: Thank you for example. You are so kind.